# Swift 3 Contacts

Tags: swift, contacts

I am using Swift Contacts and trying to determine if there is a way to cast `contacts.phoneNumbers` as a `NSDictionary`? 
i.e. values can be accessed in `contacts.phoneNumbers` this way:

```
self.officePhone.text = (contact.phoneNumbers[0].value ).value(forKey: "digits")as! String
```

Where the count is determined by how many phone numbers are entered for each contact by the user, however if I print the `contact.phoneNumbers`, I get a string like so:

```
label=_$!<Main>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x1452c870: countryCode=us, digits=7323214682>>
```

Where as it appears it is a key value pair, however if I try to cast to a `NSDictionary` for easy access I get Error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'CNLabeledValue to
>   expected argument types [AnyHashable : Any]

Any thoughts?

Comment: The `phoneNumbers` property of `CNContact` is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, thanks got it. But is there a way to tell how the user labeled them ?

Comment: Loop through the list of `CNLabeledValue` instances. The `label` property is the label. The `value` property is the `CNPhoneNumber`.

Comment: Ahhhhh !!, thanks .... now I got it .

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
    extension ViewController: CNContactPickerDelegate {
        func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
            let phoneNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers
            phoneNumbers.forEach {
                if let digits = $0.value.value(forKey: "digits") {
                    print(digits)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you awesome... Much appreciated.